# Не работают сервисы в AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Создаю сервис

```
var app = angular.module("appTestApp", []);
app.service('Calculator', function () {
this.square = function () {
    console.log("This is service")
};
});
```

Пытаюсь его использовать в app.run. App.run работает отлично, а вот принимать сервис никак не хочет.

```
app.run(function ($transitions, $state) {
$transitions.onStart({}, function(transition, $state, toState, $rootScope, 
Calculator){

    console.log(Calculator)

    Calculator.square()

});
});
```

Как бы я его не пытался внедрить в app.run он все равно выдает ошибку что сервис undefuned. Например если до строки app.service в сервисе ввести console.log("hello") то строка работает. Все сыпиться на моменте app.service. Если внутрь сервиса поместить строку console.log("hello") то оно уже не выводиться.

http://prntscr.com/mct3kt

вот порядок как я подключаю скрипты.

http://prntscr.com/mct4g1

app.run идет вместе в одном файле с app.config в файле app.js

Возможно проблема что я использую одну из последних версий angularJS? В документации ничего не нашел.

Comment: так зависимости же в app.run должны подключаться `app.run(function ($transitions, $state, Calculator) {` плюс добавь ошибку из консоли, которую получаешь, если получаешь.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть этот пример будет полезен.
Способ внедрения зависимостей с помощью `$inject` выбран на основе [рекомендаций](http://devacademy.ru/posts/rukovodstvo-po-stilyu-programmirovaniya-i-oformleniya-prilozhenij-na-angularjs/)

Можно было бы написать и так

```
.run(['Calculator', function(Calculator) {...обращаемся к Calculator}]);
```

```js
angular.module("appTestApp", [])
 .service('Calculator', Calculator)
 // Один из способов внедрения зависимостей.
 // При использовании закомментировать
 // строку с `initFn.$inject = ['Calculator']`
 //.run(['Calculator', initFn])
 .run(initFn);

angular.bootstrap(
  document.getElementById('root'),
  ['appTestApp']
);

function Calculator() {
  this.square = function() {
    console.log('From service');
  }
}

// внедряем зависимости в функцию initFn
// После этого можно объявить сервис Calculator качестве параметра    
// функции
initFn.$inject = ['Calculator'];

function initFn(Calculator) {
  console.log('From initFn');
  Calculator.square();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: без пояснений пример не будет полезен

Comment: @Grundy, пояснения возможны в ответ на возникшие вопросы. Готов их предоставить, в силу своих возможностей. Но пока никто вопросов не задал.

Comment: я задаю: чем приведенный код отличается от кода в вопросе? почему этот код работает, а код в вопросе не работает?

Comment: @Grundy, дал пояснения в ответе.

Comment: А почему код в вопросе не работал?

Comment: Потому что зависимости не были внедрены в функцию. И соответственно, undefined. Из примера кода в вопросе это не совсем очевидно. Так как `$transition` и `$state` внедряются в момент подключения ui-router.

Comment: http://docs.ng.sxisa.org/guide/di#module-methods

Comment: Вся необходимая информация должна быть непосредственно в ответе

Comment: что за ссылка на какой-то левый китайский сайт? Почему не на [официальную документацию](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#module-methods)?